# Scrolling in a fixed div

Tags: html, css

So I want to create a "pop-up" that includes some settings so its not cluttered over the whole site, but when I do this with a fixed div its not scrollable, so some users can't see everything. Heres my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="settings"> <div id="settingsContent">
<div style="height: 2000px;"> test </div>
</div> </div>
```

CSS:

```
#settings {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#settingsContent {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background-color: #F3F3F3;
border: 3px solid #111111;
padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
border-radius: 0.5rem;
position: auto;
}
```

I tried using `overflow-y: scroll;` but then I could only scroll down but not up. Is there a way to fix this or a alternative?

Comment: #settingsContent need to be centered vertically?

Comment: Yeah, I would like that it's in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `max-height: 100%;` to `div#settingsContent`. This will prevent it from overlapping the containing div.

You should also add back `overflow-y: scroll;`, and remove `position: auto;`, which is not a valid value for position.

Here's a pen: https://codepen.io/jaredloson/pen/OEOLre